# Why can't I make this request to Twitter from Postman?

Tags: postman, twitter-api-v2

Why can't I make this request to Twitter from Postman?

I created a FREE Developer Account, created a project, got the keys.

FREE Account should allow me to do these requests:

[image]

In Postman, I configured properly the Environment:

[image]

[image]

When I make a request "GET User by ID", everything works fine:

[image]

However, when I make a request "POST Create a Tweet", I get "Forbidden" response:

[image]

But according to the permission level for a FREE Developer plan, this call is allowed.

Any idea why this happens?

Thank you.

Comment: WHat headers are returned in the response?